# Java replaceAll() only replaces one instance

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I would like to use string.replaceAll() to replace all sequences of characters **beginning with '@', '$', or ':'**, and **ending with a ' '(space)**. So far I have this:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[@:$]+.*?(?= )", "ZZZZ");
```

However, the regex used only replaces the first instance that meets the above criteria. So, given the string:

```
"SELECT title FROM Name WHERE nickname = :nickname AND givenName = @givenName AND familyName = $familyName"
```

Current (incorrect) output:

```
"SELECT title FROM Name WHERE nickname = ZZZZ AND givenName = @givenName AND familyName = $familyName"
```

Desired output:

```
"SELECT title FROM Name WHERE nickname = ZZZZ AND givenName = ZZZZ AND familyName = ZZZZ"
```

How can I edit the regex to produce the desired output?

Comment: [That's not the output I get.](http://ideone.com/SmCYgl)

Comment: Also, `[...]$familyName"` doesn't end with a space.

Comment: Ah, it seems familyName not ending with a space is the error after all, good spotting sir. Any idea how to adjust the regex to still replace familyName when there is no space after it?

Comment: You could do something like `.replaceAll("[@:$]+[^ ]*", "ZZZZ")`

Comment: Why are you manipluating SQL with a regular expression? Also, SQL `char` types need to be surrounded with ``'``(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you can use the following statement:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[@:$]+[^ ]*", "ZZZZ");
```

`[^...]` matches all characters except those followed by `^`.

Possible applications:

1. One time processing of human-written files (need to control the outcome, there might be Strings containing `@:$`
2. Maybe modifying some debug output so it can be executed in a DBMS

It might be safer to restrict to something like `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*` instead of `[^ ]*`.

Comment: Btw. if you need it to process files you could also use an advanced text editor like editPlus, enter the regex and quickly click through the replacement to have supervision.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the words starting with those characters then you can use this code:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[@:$]+\\w+", "ZZZZ");
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT4vR8/1)**

[image]